# Can't understand where backlight pins are in this LCD module

Tags: lcd, backlight

I have this LCD display: [RC0802A-BIW-CSX](http://www.tme.eu/it/Document/b9a90e4c309177e2c1fe2b8e3b5bba57/RC0802A-BIW-CSX.pdf)

It is supposed to have a backlight, but I can't understand where the backlight LED is since the connections are just 14 pin, and backlight is not mentioned. Any idea?

Comment: If you have it physically, then you could show a photo. I am sure these kinds have visible backlight pins.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> connections are just 14 pin, and backlight is not mentioned

The backlight LED connections are not on the same connector.  They are on the opposite side of the module.

[image: drawing from the datasheet]
(drawing from p.7 in the [datasheet](http://www.tme.eu/it/Document/b9a90e4c309177e2c1fe2b8e3b5bba57/RC0802A-BIW-CSX.pdf))

Such an arrangement is not uncommon for character LCDs.  [Here's another example.](http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/291/NHD-0216K1Z-FL-YBW-42789.pdf)

Answer (score 2):

A backlight is mentioned in many places, but that doesn't help. They don't show the connection in detail.

Page 7 shows two letters, **A** and **K**, on one side of the LCD. That's the backlight. It doesn't show *how* and *where* they are, or how to connect to it.

Page 12 has the electrical characteristics for the backlight. Apparently it's a pretty standard white LED, they want you to drive it with a current of 16 mA, and then it will develop about 3.5 V.